# Redirecting subprocess.run() stderr from Python script

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stderr

**Context:** I'm using the SRA-toolkit to download to download accessions from the SRA. After downloading the .sra files their integrity needs to be checked by using `vdb-validate accession` which outputs stderr to the terminal. I want to capture this stderr to a file to be processed later.

**Problem:** Whereas `vdb-validate accession &> validation_file.txt` works perfectly, storing the stderr in validation_file.txt and not printing anything to the terminal; after calling the same command using subprocess.run() from a Python script using `subprocess.run(["vdb-validate", accession, "&>", validation_file])` *(accession and validation_file are variables)* the output is printed to the terminal and nothing is written to the file.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I'm using Python 3.6.8 on a Linux server

Answer (score 0):

subprocess allows you to catch the `stdout`:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
'Hello World!\n'
```

you may easily redirect `stderr` to the `stdout` as well using `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(
...     "ls non_existent_file; exit 0",
...     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
...     shell=True)
'ls: non_existent_file: No such file or directory\n'
```